# Enunciate Reporting - Error The 'assemble' goal requires 'war' packaging

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, enunciate

I am getting the error while running the below command while generating enunciate report

```
mvn clean pre-site site:site site:stage -PskipQuality -DskipTests=true -U
```

My pom.xml's enunciate plugin configuration below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.27</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>assemble</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Error - 'assemble' goal requires 'war' packaging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the below configuration under executing tag, the error stopped coming.

```
<configuration>
<forceWarPackaging>false</forceWarPackaging>
</configuration>
```

Comment: could you provide more information, there is no `executing` tag and adding above `configuration` tag after `execution` generates problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to package the project as war:

```
<project>
  ...
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention - My product is built with RPM packaging.